# Submit an Amazon MWS GetMyFeesEstimate API Request

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I'm trying to retrieve the Fees Estimate for a specific SKU using the Amazon MWS API.  I have the Sample files and have read and read but I cannot figure out how to actually specify the SKU for submission.

I have the Sample file GetMyFeesEstimateSample.php working against the mock file, but that is the response file, isn't it?

Here is what I have, how do I specify the SellerSKU for the request?

```
<?php
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright 2009-2016 Amazon Services. All Rights Reserved.
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
 *
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at: http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0
 * This file is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR 
 * CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the 
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
 *******************************************************************************
 * PHP Version 5
 * @category Amazon
 * @package  Marketplace Web Service Products
 * @version  2011-10-01
 * Library Version: 2016-06-01
 * Generated: Fri Sep 16 11:49:32 PDT 2016
 */

/**
 * Get My Fees Estimate Sample
 */

require_once('.config.inc.php');

/************************************************************************
 * Instantiate Implementation of MarketplaceWebServiceProducts
 *
 * AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY constants
 * are defined in the .config.inc.php located in the same
 * directory as this sample
 ***********************************************************************/
// More endpoints are listed in the MWS Developer Guide
// North America:
//$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01";
// Europe
//$serviceUrl = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01";
// Japan
//$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.jp/Products/2011-10-01";
// China
//$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com.cn/Products/2011-10-01";


 $config = array (
   'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
   'ProxyHost' => null,
   'ProxyPort' => -1,
   'ProxyUsername' => null,
   'ProxyPassword' => null,
   'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
 );

 $service = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client(
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        APPLICATION_NAME,
        APPLICATION_VERSION,
        $config);

/************************************************************************
 * Uncomment to try out Mock Service that simulates MarketplaceWebServiceProducts
 * responses without calling MarketplaceWebServiceProducts service.
 *
 * Responses are loaded from local XML files. You can tweak XML files to
 * experiment with various outputs during development
 *
 * XML files available under MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Mock tree
 *
 ***********************************************************************/
 // $service = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Mock();

/************************************************************************
 * Setup request parameters and uncomment invoke to try out
 * sample for Get My Fees Estimate Action
 ***********************************************************************/
 // @TODO: set request. Action can be passed as MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMyFeesEstimate
 $request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMyFeesEstimateRequest();
 $request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
 // object or array of parameters
 invokeGetMyFeesEstimate($service, $request);

/**
  * Get Get My Fees Estimate Action Sample
  * Gets competitive pricing and related information for a product identified by
  * the MarketplaceId and ASIN.
  *
  * @param MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Interface $service instance of MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Interface
  * @param mixed $request MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMyFeesEstimate or array of parameters
  */

  function invokeGetMyFeesEstimate(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Interface $service, $request)
  {
      try {
        $response = $service->GetMyFeesEstimate($request);

        echo ("Service Response\n");
        echo ("=============================================================================\n");

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        echo $dom->saveXML();
        echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");

     } catch (MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Exception $ex) {
        echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
        echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
        echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
        echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
        echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
     }
 }
```

I found this, but I still have no idea what to do.  You'd think the Amazon Samples would include a Sample ASIN or SKU; https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMyFeesEstimate.html

[image: Get Fees]

Answer (score 5):

Was programming this yesterday and found out the solution, for more info regarding the FeesEstimateRequestElements:

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_Datatypes.html#FeesEstimateRequest

Info about the operation GetMyFeesEstimate:

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMyFeesEstimate.html

GetMyFeesEstimateSample with some comments, this works:

```
<?php

require_once('.config.inc.php');


$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01";

 $config = array (
   'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
   'ProxyHost' => null,
   'ProxyPort' => -1,
   'ProxyUsername' => null,
   'ProxyPassword' => null,
   'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
 );

 $service = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client(
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        APPLICATION_NAME,
        APPLICATION_VERSION,
        $config);


//First we set up all the list variables 
$FeesEstimateRequest = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_FeesEstimateRequest();
$FeesEstimateRequest->setMarketplaceId('ATVPDKIKX0DER'); // Amazon.com marketplace id
$FeesEstimateRequest->setIdType('SellerSKU');             // IdType values: ASIN, SellerSKU, SellerSKU in your case
$FeesEstimateRequest->setIdValue('XXXXXXXXXX');       // The value of the id you have entered
$FeesEstimateRequest->setIdentifier('request1');          // A identifier for the item you have requested, this is for your own use 
$FeesEstimateRequest->setIsAmazonFulfilled(FALSE);        // Fullfilled by Amazon? true if the offer is fulfilled by Amazon.    

//To set up the $PriceToEstimateFees object we need two instances of the object MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_MoneyType
//@ set up for both cases: Listing Price and Shipping Price  
//New object MoneyType, setting up the currency and amount for listing price
$MoneyTypeListingPrice = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_MoneyType();
$MoneyTypeListingPrice->setCurrencyCode('USD'); // String, the currency code of the price : USD in this example for amazon.com marketplace
$MoneyTypeListingPrice->setAmount('0.00');      // String, the price of the item 

//New object MoneyType, setting up the currency and amount for shipping price
$MoneyTypeShipping = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_MoneyType();
$MoneyTypeShipping->setCurrencyCode('USD'); // String, the currency code of the price : USD in this example for amazon.com marketplace
$MoneyTypeShipping->setAmount('0.00');       // String, the price of the item 

//Setting up the prices: Listing Price and Shipping Price
$PriceToEstimateFees = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_PriceToEstimateFees();
$PriceToEstimateFees->setListingPrice($MoneyTypeListingPrice);
$PriceToEstimateFees->setShipping($MoneyTypeShipping);

//Finally setting up the $PriceToEstimateFees object to the $FeesEstimateRequest object 
$FeesEstimateRequest->setPriceToEstimateFees($PriceToEstimateFees); // The product price that the fee estimate is based on. 

//setting up the final required parameter in the $FeesEstimateRequestList object
$FeesEstimateRequestList = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_FeesEstimateRequestList();
$FeesEstimateRequestList->setFeesEstimateRequest($FeesEstimateRequest);

// Last step : sending the $FeesEstimateRequestList object into $request
$request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMyFeesEstimateRequest();
$request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
$request->setFeesEstimateRequestList($FeesEstimateRequestList);
// object or array of parameters
invokeGetMyFeesEstimate($service, $request);



 function invokeGetMyFeesEstimate(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Interface $service, $request)
  {
  try {
    $response = $service->GetMyFeesEstimate($request);

    echo ("Service Response\n");
    echo ("=============================================================================\n");

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    echo $dom->saveXML();
    echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");

 } catch (MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Exception $ex) {
    echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
    echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
    echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
    echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
    echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
    echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
    echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
 }
}
```

Comment: Was this of help?

Answer (score 2):

As part of your request, you submit a `FeesEstimateRequestList`  In that list, you specifiy the `IdType`, which can be `ASIN` or `SellerSKU`.  Then you give it a value in `IdValue`.  Note that there are other elements that are required.  Check out the `FeesEstimateRequest` for those elements right here https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_Datatypes.html#FeesEstimateRequest

Your POST above has an `ASIN` defined instead of `SellerSKU` for `IdType`.   Just change that to `SellerSKU` like I mentioned above and you'll be set.

I use the [C# SDK](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/cSharp.html/163-1317503-1839417) which has examples for all this.  I would assume the [PHP SDK](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/php.html/163-1317503-1839417) would be the same, but maybe it's as complete.  In any case, you need to submit a `FeesEstimateRequestList` in your POST so MWS knows what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, the screen shot is from the Amazon website, not my request.  That is the bit I am struggling to understand, how do I form and submit the request.  I will be running multiple requests in a loop.

Comment: I'm not a php guy, but the end result is to produce a POST to MWS.  You can hand code it and submit or use Amazon's SDK.  Looking at the PHP code above, it looks like you need to uncomment this line: "* @param mixed $request MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMyFeesEstimate or array of parameters" and put your parameters in there.  It's a bit foreign to me.   Take a look around stackoverflow for examples.  Maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416063/fetch-product-from-amazon-mws-using-product-api